# Passing an equals sign into cdk --tags value via npm run script

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, aws-cdk

I'm trying to pass a '--tags' value containing an equals sign to the cdk binary via an npm script.
The tag named 'tagname' should contain the literal text 'valuea=5:valueb=5'. I'm trying to call cdk as follows

```
npm run cdk -- deploy teststack --tags tagname=valuea=5:valueb=5
```

Which results in the tag's value to equal 'valuea'. I reckon its trying to parse the text after the '=' as a new tag value. I tried to resolve this by putting the tag value in quotes like this:

```
npm run cdk -- deploy teststack --tags tagname="valuea=5:valueb=5"
```

but npm runs this command as follows:

```
cdk "deploy" "teststack" "--tags" "tagname=valuea=5:valueb=5"
```

as you can see each argument is put between quotes and the quotes I provided are removed.

Is there a way to prevent npm run from removing and adding these quotes?

I tried to escape my quotes like this

```
npm run cdk -- deploy teststack --tags tagname=\"valuea=5:valueb=5\"
```

which results in

```
cdk "deploy" "teststack" "--tags" "tagname=\"valuea=5:valueb=5\""
```

which fails the cdk deploy with

```
The Tag Value provided is invalid "valuea (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: xxx; Proxy: null)
```

Comment: try `tagname=\"valuea=5:valueb=5\"`

Comment: Ah I've tried this, I just edited my question to include this.

Comment: The quotes just prevent the _shell_ from doing anything with the value; the quotes will be processed by the shell, and will be gone by the time `npm` actually runs.

Comment: instead of using tags, use context values. `-c SomeValue=MyThing` you can repeat this as many times as you need `-c SomeValue=MyThing -c AnotherVlaue=AnotherThing` - these can then be accessed in CDK https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/get_context_var.html - you can pass those as env variables to a codebuild or something then. You can also default them in the cdk.json file.

Comment: so i would do something like -c valuea=5 -c valueb=10 and then using the context variables in your code, apply them wherever is needed. I make use of this to differenatiate a stack deployment from Prod or Non-Prod deployments (-c deployment_tag=PROD)